# Compiler error when trying to read message values

Tags: ros, c++, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is my SWrite.msg file

```
int16 id
int16 pos
int16 time
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# %Tag(FULLTEXT)%
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(scs_servo_control)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg)

add_message_files(FILES SWrite.msg)

generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

catkin_package()

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable(scs_listener src/scs_listener.cpp)
add_library(hardwareserial src/HardwareSerial.cpp)
add_library(scservo src/SCServo.cpp)
add_library(scsprotocol src/SCSProtocol.cpp)
target_link_libraries(scs_listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES} hardwareserial scservo scsprotocol)
add_dependencies(scs_listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

# %EndTag(FULLTEXT)%
```

And here is my callback function:

```
void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  int id = msg->id;
}
```

I get compiler error with this:

```
/home/serge/NetBeansProjects/ROS_beginner_tutorials/ros_ws/src/scs_servo_control/src/scs_listener.cpp: In function ‘void chatterCallback(const ConstPtr&)’:
/home/serge/NetBeansProjects/ROS_beginner_tutorials/ros_ws/src/scs_servo_control/src/scs_listener.cpp:26:19: error: ‘const struct std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘id’
     int id = msg->id;
                   ^
scs_servo_control/CMakeFiles/scs_listener.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'scs_servo_control/CMakeFiles/scs_listener.dir/src/scs_listener.cpp.o' failed
```

It seems to be logical, because id (and also pos and time) is nowhere defined as member.

But I read this
https://answers.ros.org/question/54587/reading-message-once-subscribed-to-a-topic/

and this

https://answers.ros.org/question/158976/how-to-read-a-value-from-a-ros-message/

and it confuses me.

So how can I read values from a message in my callback function? What I missed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268845/compiler-error-when-trying-to-read-message-values/) by [Sergey Kravchenko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27657/sergey-kravchenko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2017-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> And here is my callback function:

> ```
> void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
> ```

```
{
  int id = msg->id;
}
```

you define a custom message (`SWrite.msg`), but in your callback signature you still appear to be using `std_msgs::String`. That doesn't make sense to me.

The error message ("there is no field `id` in `std_msgs::String`") does make sense in that case.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1